# Asking for Administrator permission in a WPF application despite setting requestedExecutionLevel to "requireAdministrator" in .NET 5

Tags: .net, wpf, admin, uac

I developed a WPF application using .NET 5 and I must run it with administrator privileges. I have created a setup project and added the primary output of my WPF application to it.

To accomplish this, I have made sure to set the requestedExecutionLevel attribute to "requireAdministrator" within the application manifest file (app.manifest).

However, I have encountered an issue where the application does not initiate with elevated privileges as intended. Instead, it prompts the user for Administrator permission when launched.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, guidance, or solutions to help me ensure that my WPF application starts with the necessary Administrator permission by default. Thank you sincerely for your assistance.

Comment: Unsure if I misunderstand but if Windows UAC settings demands user approval for admin level, you have to get the permission. You set your app to ask for administrator level then the app asks when launched. You could turn off UAC if only for youself, but it would be a bad way to go. You could also create a Scheduler task that starts an exe file as admin without asking, and then create a shortcut to run the task. I start my Visual Studio this way. Get back here if you want more info on this approach. But none of this helps for an app lots of people are gonna use. Need admin? Gonna ask for it :-)